# PDPageContentStream has no drawLine() method

Tags: java, eclipse, pdfbox

So I just started using Apache PDFBox (0.7.3) in one of my projects to write to PDF. I want to draw a line across the whole page, which according to [the docs](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/edit/PDPageContentStream.html) and many examples I have seen, I should be able to do by calling the drawLine() method from my PDPageContentStream. However, in Eclipse I only see two drawImage methods and a drawString method. Does anyone know what I should do to fix this? Is the drawLine method deprecated or something?

Comment: A little bit offtopic, but please update to a more recent version of PDFBox http://pdfbox.apache.org

Comment: This is the latest version I see in Maven...

Comment: I overlooked the version you mentioned (0.7.3). That indeed is ancient. Probably the group of the artifact meanwhile has changed.

Comment: @mkl Yeah, I just checked. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/pdfbox/pdfbox lists 0.7.3 as the latest version, while http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/1.8.4 is the correct group for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [`PDPageContentStream`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/pdfbox/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/edit/PDPageContentStream.java) I see:

```
/**
 * Draw a line on the page using the current non stroking color and the current line width.
 *
 * @param xStart The start x coordinate.
 * @param yStart The start y coordinate.
 * @param xEnd The end x coordinate.
 * @param yEnd The end y coordinate.
 * @throws IOException If there is an error while drawing on the screen.
 */
public void drawLine(float xStart, float yStart, float xEnd, float yEnd) throws IOException
{
    if (inTextMode)
    {
        throw new IOException("Error: drawLine is not allowed within a text block.");
    }
    addLine(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd);
    // stroke
    stroke();
}
```

Thus, either your PDFBox copy is outdated or your eclipse does not show existing methods.

I use eclipse Kepler here and see the method all right.

It is located between `addLine` and `addPolygon` in the source, far away from `drawImage` or `drawString`. If you are searching in the outline, you maybe should activate sort-by-name there.